# NINTEX Form - Javascript: get weekdays between two dates inside repeater

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I created my own javascript code to get weekdays between two dates in Nintex Form.
I have two datepicker with cssclass name: **DateFromStr** and **DateToStr**.
And a single line text with client ID javascript name **jsText**.
The reason why I put a cssclass name for my datepicker because actually DateFromStr and DateToStr is not really a datepicker.
My datepicker automatically return a date with format dd/MM/yyyy and it disturb when I tried to calculate, so I pass the value from datepicker to CalculatedValue into MM/dd/yyyy format.
The code below is working fine, but when I try to put all the controls inside a repeater it doesn't work.
I think to call the repeater name is the best way, I tried but it doesn't work. I need your suggestion for this. Thank you so much.

```
function calculate()
{
 var dateFrom=new Date();var dateTo=new Date();

 var jsFrom=NWF$('.DateFromStr').find('input');
 var jsTo=NWF$('.DateToStr').find('input');

 dateFrom=new Date(jsFrom.val());
 dateTo=new Date(jsTo.val());

 var iWeeks, iDateDiff, iAdjust = 0;

 var iWeekday1=dateFrom.getDay();
 var iWeekday2=dateTo.getDay();

 iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday1;
 iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday2;

 if ((iWeekday1 > 5) && (iWeekday2 > 5))
 {iAdjust = 1;} 
 iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday1;
 iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday2;

 iWeeks = Math.floor((dateTo.getTime() - dateFrom.getTime()) / 604800000) ;

 if (iWeekday1 <= iWeekday2)
 {iDateDiff = (iWeeks * 5) + (iWeekday2 - iWeekday1);}
 else
 {iDateDiff = ((iWeeks + 1) * 5) - (iWeekday1 - iWeekday2);}
 iDateDiff -= iAdjust;

 var result=iDateDiff+1;

 var txt=NWF$("#"+jsText);
 txt.val(result);


}
```

Comment: Show us the code with your repeater, so we can identify what went wrong.

Comment: my repeater doesn't have any code. I use Nintex form. I just drag drop from the menu control.